# Everytime I change WP from subdir to root, site loads fine, but Elementor fails

Tags: wordpress, path, load, elementor

I'm frequenty hired to renew web sites. So I install WP on a subdir while the old site keeps working.
EXAMPLE.COM would be original site, then EXAMPLE.COM/web the new site.

Once the customer is satisfied, I bakcup the old site and the new one, change Site Address(URL) on WP settings, copy index.php to root and modify path. Then the site loads OK as EXAMPLE.COM, hiding the folder.

BUT when I try to edit a page with Elementor, it wont load.

I've tried:
IN ELEMENTOR

1. Regenerating CSS & Data
2. Sync Library
3. Safe Mode
4. Replace URL
   IN WP
5. Change and rollback permalinks
6. Disable all plugins

No worries about server specs here, as the site was loading on the subdir path and is loading on the new path

Also, not a cache issue, as I've tried this.

Sometimes after a day, elementor will load fine. Sometimes, I have to fetch the backup and try again.
I know there's something I'm missing here...

Comment: `Sometimes after a day, elementor will load fine` cache / CDN maybe?

Comment: UPDATE: A few hours later I tried loading on another device and it was fine. So I tried on the original device, and wouldn't load. Then I restarted the browser and there you go, everything in order. So now I'm thinkin Elementor keeps data on the browser's cache (not only server cache) that was blocking me.